# library not found for -ljschelpers

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to upgrade from rn 56 to rn 57,58 and now 59
In all my tries I get following error when try to build after `npm install`:

```
info ld: library not found for -ljschelpers
```

I cleared **ios/build** folder I cleared **derivedData** folder and nothing works.
I cleared whole **node-modules** folder.
Does anybody has idea what this could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case what I think helped me was removing `libjschelpers.a` from `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, I think this was replaced with `JavaScriptCore.framework` and caused collision.

Other thing I did was basically removing and adding again all libraries in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` that did not have the "temple" icon, plus `JavaScriptCore.framework`.
Besides `libjschelpers.a` I also removed `libyoga.a`, `libReact.a`, `libcxxreact.a`, `libz.tbd` as these are not present in newly created RN project.